# D'où vient l'expression "Jeanne, au secours !" et que signifie-t-elle ?

Tags: grammaire

D'où vient l'expression "Jeanne, au secours !" et que signifie-t-elle ?

Comment: Jean-Marie Lepen shouted this on May 1st 2015 in front of a statue of Jeanne d'Arc. Are you asking why he did this?

Comment: Have you researched this phrase online?  There is a wikipedia page that turns up quite quickly.  Tu peux vérifier et répondre.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comit%C3%A9s_Jeanne

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comit%C3%A9s_Jeanne

Answer (score 1):

En 2015, Jean-Marie le Pen, homme politique français d'extrême droite, cria cette phrase au pied de la statue de Jeanne d'Arc sur la place du Martroi à Orléans, devant de nombreuses caméras.

Jeanne d'Arc est utilisée ici pour véhiculer un fort sentiment nationaliste de "lutte contre l'envahisseur". Figure historique de France, née au XVe siècle, elle revendiquant avoir été investie d'une mission sacrée et consacra sa vie à lutter contre l'invasion anglaise en tant que cheffe de guerre.

Suite à son exclusion du Front National par sa fille en 2016, il créait le parti [Comités Jeanne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comit%C3%A9s_Jeanne) et réutilisa cette phrase comme slogan.